# PHP shell_exec works in terminal, but displays no output on webpage

Tags: php, python, scripting, shell-exec

As the title says, I am running a python script from PHP using shell_exec, and this works when running it from a SSH session into my web server by running 'php ./python.php'. I get the expected output.

However when the page is loaded on a web browser, I simply get a blank web page with no PHP warnings or errors. Any help is appreciated.

**python.php:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 ./test.py 2>&1");
$output =  shell_exec($command);
echo $output;


?>
```

**test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import pandas as pd
import math
import csv

url = 'https://afltables.com/afl/stats/2018a.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
dfs = dfs[1]

dfs.to_csv('hmm.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8');
dfs = dfs[dfs.TM == "NM"]
dfs = dfs[dfs.GM > 3]

url = 'https://afltables.com/afl/seas/2018.html'
lad = pd.read_html(url)

scores = []


for index, row in dfs.iterrows():
    score = (math.sqrt(row['CP']) * 2 + (row['IF']) * 2 + (row['CL']) ** 2)
    scores.append([row['Player'], score])

pos = 1
scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for item in scores:
    print(str(pos) + ". " + item[0] + ": " + str(item[1]))
    pos = pos + 1
```

Comment: is your python script meant to output the total score in the end?

Comment: @Sajan No, it outputs a series of scores.